# Use of multiple IF conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to get a cell to pick a cell of data from a table using IF (Excel 2010, can't do IFS), but when I try to nest more than 2 IF, it returns a "too many arguments" error. Formula at this point:

```
=IF(B11="Humain",VLOOKUP(COO,Fonctions!A88:M110,2,FALSE),IF(OR(B11="Hybride Naturel",B11="Géno-Hybride"),VLOOKUP(COO,Fonctions!A88:M110,3,FALSE)))
```

Where am I doing it wrong? :/

Comment: The problem is too many commas, I would break down each individual if statement and make sure it works the way you want it to. Then merge them together.

Comment: The formula as posted works just fine, I just can't add any further IF arguments to it, and I'd need to add an extra 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a final comma should the second `IF` condition return false. Update your formula like so:

```
=IF(B11="Humain",VLOOKUP(COO,Fonctions!A88:M110,2,FALSE),IF(OR(B11="Hybride Naturel",B11="Géno-Hybride"),VLOOKUP(COO,Fonctions!A88:M110,3,FALSE),"N/A"))
```

Notice the `N/A` that will be produced should both `IF` statements do not yield any results.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! I managed therefore to slip extra IF conditions in. Thanks Gareth. +1

Comment: @GavinC Glad to help. If the answer helped, consider accepting it by clicking the arrow to the left of it :).

Comment: Already done that! My reputation isn't high enough to show the upvote. You just helped out a brand spanking newbie :)